# Algorithms to find min/max of a single variable function in fixed domain

Tags: python, algorithm, max, min, numerical-methods

I was looking for a **numerical** algorithm to find **global** minimum or maximum of a function in "given interval [a, b]", for example finding minimum and maximum of function

> f(x) = sin(x)

in domain [3*pi/4, 5*pi/4].

I know how to find global min/max of a multi-variable function using Gradient Descent or Gradient Ascend, but I'm only able to use these algorithms on entire function domain, for example when I use GD on function sin(x), it gives me -1 which is correct for domain [0, 2*pi] not [3*pi/4, 5*pi/4], any help?

I have reached to this solution so far (code in python 2.7, language isn't important, my questions is about Algorithms):

```
import math
import random

# function
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)

# xmin-xmax interval
xmin = 3.0 * math.pi / 4.0
xmax = 5.0 * math.pi / 4.0

# find ymin-ymax
steps = 10000
ymin = f(xmin)
ymax = ymin

for i in range(steps):
    x = xmin + (xmax - xmin) * float(i) / steps
    y = f(x)
    if y < ymin: ymin = y
    if y > ymax: ymax = y

print ymin
print ymax
```

**answer**

thanks to @BlackBear, I wrote a program that does what i actually need, this function searches through interval [a, b] using Gradient Descent algorithm, on each loop it start with a new random starting point between a and b, then compares the values, at the end it returns the x where the minimum occurs

```
double gradientDescentInterval(const char *expression, double a, double b, double ete, double ere, double gamma,
                               unsigned int maxiter, int mode) {
    /*
     * Gradient descent is a first-order iterative optimization algorithm for finding the minimum of a function.
     * To find a local minimum of a function using gradient descent, one takes steps proportional to the negative of
     * the gradient (or approximate gradient) of the function at the current point.
     *
     * This function searches minimum on an interval [a, b]
     *
     * ARGUMENTS:
     * expressions  the function expression, it must be a string array like "x^2+1"
     * a            starting point of interval [a, b]
     * b            ending point of interval [a, b]
     * ete          estimated true error
     * ere          estimated relative error
     * gamma        step size (also known as learning rate)
     * maxiter      maximum iteration threshold
     * mode         show process {0: no, 1: yes}
     *
     */

    // fix interval reverse
    if (a > b) {
        double temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    } // end of if

    // check error thresholds
    if (ere < 0 || ete < 0) {
        printf("\nError: ete or ere argument is not valid\n");
        Exit();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // end of if

    // check mode
    if (mode != 0 && mode != 1) {
        printf("\nError: mode argument is not valid\n");
        Exit();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // end of if

    // check maxiter to be more than zero
    if (maxiter <= 0) {
        printf("Error: argument maxiter must be more than zero!\n");
        Exit();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // end of maxiter check

    // initializing variables
    unsigned int iter = 0, innerIter = 0;
    // choose an arbitrary result at midpoint between a and b to be updated later
    double coefficient = (b - a), result = a + coefficient / 2;
    double x, past_x, fx, fresult;
    double ete_err, ere_err;
    double fa = function_1_arg(expression, a);
    double fb = function_1_arg(expression, b);

    // set the seed for random number generator
    seed();

    while (iter < maxiter) {
        // try maxiter times to find minimum in given interval [a, b] and return lowest result
        // update fresult with new result
        fresult = function_1_arg(expression, result);
        // choose a random starting point
        x = a + coefficient * zeroToOneUniformRandom();

        // set inner iter to zero before new loop
        innerIter = 0;
        // go in a loop to find a minimum with random starting point
        while (innerIter < maxiter) {
            // calculate new x by subtracting the derivative of function at x multiplied by gamma from x
            past_x = x;
            x -= firstDerivative_1_arg(expression, x, DX) * gamma;
            fx = function_1_arg(expression, x);

            // calculate errors
            ete_err = fabs(past_x - x);
            ere_err = fabs(ete_err / x);

            if (mode) {
                printf("\nIn this iteration [#%d][#%d], x = %.5e f(x) = %.5e\n"
                       "and estimated true error = %.5e and estimated relative error = %.5e,\n",
                       iter, innerIter, x, fx, ete_err, ere_err);
            } // end if(mode)

            // Termination Criterion
            // if new x goes beyond interval lower than a
            if (x < a) {
                if (mode) {
                    printf("\nIn this iteration the calculated x is less than a : %.5e < %f"
                           "so minimum of the function occurs at a\n",
                           x, a);
                } // end if(mode)

                // if fa is lower than f(result), then a is where the minimum occurs
                if (fa < fresult) {
                    result = a;
                } // end of if
                break;
            } // end of if

            // if new x goes beyond interval bigger than b
            if (x > b) {
                if (mode) {
                    printf("\nIn this iteration the calculated x is bigger than b : %.5e > %f"
                           "so minimum of the function occurs at b\n",
                           x, b);
                } // end if(mode)

                // if fb is lower than f(result), then b is where the minimum occurs
                if (fb < fresult) {
                    result = b;
                } // end of if
                break;
            } // end of if

            // if calculated error is less than estimated true error threshold
            if (ete != 0 && ete_err < ete) {
                if (mode) {
                    printf("\nIn this iteration the calculated estimated true error is less than the threshold\n"
                           "(estimated true error) %.5e < %.5e (threshold)\n"
                           "so the calculated x is the point on domain that minimum of the function happens\n",
                           ete_err, ete);
                } // end if(mode)

                // if fx is lower than f(result), then x is where the minimum occurs
                if (fx < fresult) {
                    result = x;
                } // end of if
                break;
            } // end of estimated true error check

            // if calculated error is less than estimated relative error threshold
            if (ere != 0 && ere_err < ere) {
                if (mode) {
                    printf("\nIn this iteration the calculated estimated real error is less than the threshold\n"
                           "(estimated real error) %.5e < %.5e (threshold)\n"
                           "so the calculated x is the point on domain that minimum of the function happens\n",
                           ere_err, ere);
                } // end if(mode)

                // if fx is lower than f(result), then x is where the minimum occurs
                if (fx < fresult) {
                    result = x;
                } // end of if
                break;
            } // end of estimated relative error check
            innerIter++;
        } // end of inner while loop
        iter++;
    } // end of while loop

    // return result
    return result;
}
```

many functions here are may seem unknown to you, they are coded in separate files. you can see them at [my Github repository](https://github.com/MahdiBaghbani/C-Math/tree/development).

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. What do you call a *fixed* domain ? Are you after *global* or *local* maxima ? Analytical or numerical solution ? 1D or nD ?

Comment: If you are looking for a *general purpose, bulletproof* numerical optimization algorithm, be aware that this does not exist.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, it was my first question on stack overflow [and internet at all], I didn't know where to start.

Comment: It would help to know what the application is and what you truly require.  For example do you need the exact value for analytic functions or close approximations, and do you need the location of said global min/max?  For a periodic function you will have a set of min/max and does it matter that you catch all of them?  I have implemented many algorithms for finding global max in data, some are pretty simple if your requirements are not too stringent.

Comment: I would say consider using [Brent's method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brent.html), but since you want a global max it's not going to satisfy your requirement. @YvesDaoust's comment is pertinent.

Comment: @ggcg I just need approximated values not analytical ones,  and yes i need locations (x) not the values itself, for periodic ones I just need the lowest one in interval [a, b], let's say we have y = x*sin(x) in interval [0, 20], I need the x where the lowest y occurs, btw can i ask you with which algorithms you catch all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient ascent/descent can only find *local* optima, in order to find "global" optima you just run that procedure many times with random initialization, and take the best value you find.

You can do the same in your situation as well: take random initial points and follow the gradient, stopping at convergence or when you step outside the domain.

You can make this a bit faster by dynamically restricting the domain when you step out of it. For example, suppose you are maximizing between -10 and 10, and choose 6 as an initial point; you run gradient ascent and reach 10. You can now exclude the interval [6,10] from the random initialization, since you know you will end up reaching 10 and stopping there.

But I would actually advise you to use [Bayesian optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02811). Its advantages over gradient ascent/descent are:

1. does not require gradient
2. made for global optimization
3. allows to set bounds on parameters
4. requires much fewer function evaluations

Finally, obligatory word of caution: this problem cannot be solved *in the general case*, consider e.g. a function that equals `1` at `x=3.4131242351`, and `0` everywhere else. However, in practice, you should be fine.

Comment: About "excluding" intervals: It might be easier to have a list of intervals, initially holding only the entire interval. Then, randomly pop an interval from that list, randomly chose a starting point from that list, and add one or two new intervals to the list (from the interval's lower bound to min(start, optimum) and from max(start, optimium) to the upper)

Comment: @tobias_k that's a nice extension. Sadly eliminating intervals cannot be done in higher dimensions

Comment: "You can now exclude the interval [6,10]": no, unless the function has some peculiar property, you can *never* exclude an interval by simple sampling.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's not simple sampling, since we used gradient ascent we know the function is increasing in [6,10]

Comment: @BlackBear: no, you don't know that. Not at all. Sampling tells you nothing about a function.

Comment: In absolute terms, you are right, but in practice, on "normal" functions, gradient descent with small enough steps does give you that guarantee. You can be as nitpicky as you want, and you would be right in the general case, but then you cannot solve this problem in the most general case with no knowledge of the exact function.

Comment: I purposely said "unless the function has some peculiar property", which you seem to call "normal" functions. In the first place, the function must be differentiable to use gradient descent. There is a difference between being nitpicky and having experience of real-life cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you see things from a mathematician's point of view, while I see things from an engineer's point of view :) sure, continuous and differentiable functions are very rare if you consider all the possible functions, but are much more common in practical applications

Comment: @BlackBear thanks, I will try to code your solution about using Gradient descent with random initialization.